# Persist one to one undirectional mapping from parent

Tags: jpa, one-to-one

I need to persist the child automatically when I try to persist parent in one to one undirectional mapping.

Imagine I have employee parent table, and employee detail as child table both have one to one undirectional mapping.

Note: I want to have employeeId as FK in the employeedetail table.

I have followed below link.

[https://www.java4coding.com/contents/jpa/jpa-one-to-one-unidirectional-association-mapping#:~:text=One%2DTo%2DOne%20mapping%20is,object%20then%20it%20becomes%20unidirectional](https://www.java4coding.com/contents/jpa/jpa-one-to-one-unidirectional-association-mapping#:%7E:text=One%2DTo%2DOne%20mapping%20is,object%20then%20it%20becomes%20unidirectional).

In this example they are trying to save child and parent is get saved automatically.

But I need child employeedetail  to be get saved automatically when I try to persist parent employee table.

Whether there is any way I can persist one to one undirectional mapping from parent side?

Comment: Why are you making this unidirectional from EmployeeDetail-> Employee? If you must have an EmployeeDetail instance when defining an Employee, you would put that object within the Employee itself so that Every employee is created with an EmployeeDetail instance. Just map it as a bidirectional relationship, and cascade persist over the Employee->EmployeeDetail reference.  Otherwise - no, what you want is much more difficult and more easily done in your service layer.  PS that java4coding link code isn't JPA compliant. You cannot have two mappings for the EMPID column like that

Answer (score 0):

That link you posted is very wrong, but close to what you seem to need. When you define an Employee, if you want to have an EmployeeDetails instance persisted as well you must have some mechanism to get that data. To me, this implies it is built into the employee object itself so that Employee has a reference to EmployeeDetail.  Something along the lines of:

```
@Entity
public class Employee  {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Integer empId;
  @OneToOne(mappedby = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  EmployeeDetail detail;
}

@Entity
public class EmployeeDetail  {
  @Id
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="empId")
  Employee employee;
}
```

In the above suggestion, marking the employee OneToOne reference as the ID means you don't need to deal with the Employee ID value directly. This can be complicated though as you may then need to always serialize and fetch the Employee instance when looking over EmployeeDetail instances; in which case, it is common to map the fk/id as a basic mapping:

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeDetail  {
  @Id
  Integer empId;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="empId")
  @MapsId
  Employee employee;
}
```

Both ways tell JPA to set the "empId" column based on the employee reference so that you don't have to get the ID value and set it in the EmployeeDetail instance yourself. The second one though allows you to access the empId value in queries without having to risk joining to the Employee table ie:

```
  "select detail from EmployeeDetail detail where detail.employee.id = :id"
```

vs

```
  "select detail from EmployeeDetail detail where detail.empId = :id"
```

And you don't have to fetch Employee with the EmployeeDetail every time